# How do I automatically run modprobe v4l2loopback on boot?

Tags: 20.04, modprobe, obs-studio

I'm using OBS Studio and would like to have a virtual video output saved permanently so that it can be run when the application is launched.

This command creates the virtual output:

```bsh
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=10 card_label="OBS Video Source" exclusive_caps=1
```

But I must run the command in console on each boot. How can I make this permanent? The plugin that utilizes the output in OBS Studio is configured to auto start but `/dev/video10` is not available after a reboot of the system.

```
$ modinfo v4l2loopback | grep -i parm
parm:           debug:debugging level (higher values == more verbose) (int)
parm:           max_buffers:how many buffers should be allocated (int)
parm:           max_openers:how many users can open loopback device (int)
parm:           devices:how many devices should be created (int)
parm:           video_nr:video device numbers (-1=auto, 0=/dev/video0, etc.) (array of int)
parm:           card_label:card labels for every device (array of charp)
parm:           exclusive_caps:whether to announce OUTPUT/CAPTURE capabilities exclusively or not (array of bool)
parm:           max_width:maximum frame width (int)
parm:           max_height:maximum frame height (int)
```

Comment: One on the proper methods was to add the module name to the /etc/modules file . But nowadays the udev subsystem should insert the required drivers automatically . But if you are sure that it doesn't , add the name of the module to the modules file and reboot to check out the result.

Comment: There's an /etc/modprobe.d and /etc/modules-load.d but no /etc/modules directory on my system.

Comment: @Parsa Mousavi, I had erroneously looked for an /etc/modules folder rather than a file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Normally kernel modules can be added to /etc/modules for loading at boot time.

---

Add this to /etc/modules...

```
v4l2loopback video_nr=10 card_label="OBS Video Source" exclusive_caps=1
```

---

However, I don't know if you can pass parameters there. So here's another way to do it.

Add this to /etc/modules...

```
v4l2loopback
```

Create /etc/modprobe.d/v4l2loopback.conf

```
options v4l2loopback video_nr=10 card_label="OBS Video Source" exclusive_caps=1
```

---

Then...

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)

reboot
```

Confirm module loading with...

```
lsmod | grep -i v4l2loopback
```

Comment: I created /etc/modprobe.d/v4l2loopback.conf with the option and rebooted and the loopback seems to have loaded. I'll shut down and restart presently because I noticed that sometimes a reboot comes up with the settings that were present.

The result of grep same as before reboot: 
v4l2loopback           40960  0
videodev              225280  4 videobuf2_v4l2,v4l2loopback,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common

Comment: @MarkLee You added the line to /etc/modules, yes? I added an update-initramfs command to my procedure.

Comment: @MarkLee Edit your question and show me `modinfo v4l2loopback | grep -i parm`.

Comment: There's no /etc/modules on my system.

Comment: @MarkLee Create one. `sudo pico /etc/modules`. Just add `v4l2loopback` to it. Then do the update-initramfs command. Then reboot.

Comment: op edited as requested.

Comment: @MarkLee After creating both files and doing the update-initramfs, and rebooting, is it all working now?

Comment: It didn't work and as I checked  /etc/modprobe.d/v4l2loopback.conf just now what was listed in the directory instead was v4l2loopback.conf.save. I just wrote the file again and am about to reboot once more.

Comment: Keep me posted.

Comment: I think you've got me over the hump. After a few glitches--1. OBS refused to start (commented out the line in the conf and it started), 2. started with no connection to the camera (stopped the plug-in and uncommented the conf)--I have camera input and video10 output on starting. Hopefully not a one off "magic". Thanks.

Comment: @MarkLee Sounds great... I think... so, to sum up... you were able to complete the second procedure in my answer... and it seems to be working now?

Comment: Can't get this to work on 20.04. `lsmod | grep -i v4l2loopback` doesn't print anything. `❯ cat /etc/modprobe.d/v4l2loopback.conf
options v4l2loopback video_nr=10 card_label="OBS Video Source" exclusive_caps=1`

Comment: @Thor84no Did you add v4l2loopback to /etc/modules, create the .conf file, update-initramfs, and reboot?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise the `v4loopback` to `/etc/modules` was required in addition to the `/etc/modprobe.d/v4l2loopback.conf`, sorry. I guess I misread your post. It seems to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Easy way to do it un Ubuntu 20.04 and others:

```
$ sudo echo "v4l2loopback" > /etc/modules-load.d/v4l2loopback.conf 
$ sudo echo "options v4l2loopback video_nr=10 card_label=\"OBS Video Source\" exclusive_caps=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/v4l2loopback.conf
```

You can restart to check it works!

### NOTICE

Be aware of a bug on v4l2loopback-dkms 0.12.3-1ubuntu0.1

More info on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64828753/4807795).

### EDIT - Using tee

As pointed by renyhp, it's better to use the tee command:

```
$ sudo echo "v4l2loopback" | tee /etc/modules-load.d/v4l2loopback.conf 
$ sudo echo "options v4l2loopback video_nr=10 card_label=\"OBS Video Source\" exclusive_caps=1" | tee /etc/modprobe.d/v4l2loopback.conf
```

### EDIT - Update modules

As commented, it seems that in some systems after rebooting some problems can be experienced. To avoid that, it's always a good idea to update the modules:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

Comment: This is the simple answer, but it will give Permission denied, since sudo applies to echo and not to redirection. You may actually want to pipe echo into sudo tee

Comment: Actually: yes, if it used sudo tee this would be the simple way to add the needed configurations. And thank you for the warning about the bug. However, DO NOT FORGET TO DO `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` as the other answer reported. I didn't, and I regretted it (keyboard not working; had to run a live Ubuntu to remove the conf files under etc)

Comment: for me, i have trouble to downgrade v4l2loopback-dkms (installed v4l2loopback-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1) – ses just now   

actually I already have 0.12.3-1ubuntu0.4 - and problem is there too. not sure where to downgrade then.. even if I did not have error 1

Comment: @renyhp: thank you for your comments. The solution was updated.

Comment: @ses I've already commented this in the other solution.